# Volume generated by revolving the region bounded by two curves

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I'd like to ask what have I been doing wrong.

---

> Determine the volume generated by revolving the region bounded by
> the curves defined by $ y=1+x^2$ and $y=5$ about the $x$-axis.

---

I got the limits of integration to be $$x=2$$ $$x=-2$$

My solution is

$$ V=\pi \int_{-2}^{2} 5^2-(2+x^2)^2$$

I arrived at $$(2+x^2)^2$$ because I added 1 since the vertex of the curve is at (0,1) and it needs to revolve about the x-axis

Is that wrong?

Comment: What is the vertical distance from the point $(x,0)$ to the curve?

Comment: You don't need to add 1 to $y=x^2+1$. If you didn't do that, your integral is right and your final answer will be in terms of $\pi$

Comment: oh it's y itself. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for you to add that $1$. The answer is$$\pi\int_{-2}^25^2-(x^2+1)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1\,088\pi}{15}.$$